# Plot array with 3 colors in Amibroker

Tags: trading, amibroker

I am using Amibroker. I would like to make a plot of the array `PCT_CLOSE` such that the color is red when `PCT_CLOSE<=25`, yellow when between 25 and 50, Green when `PCT_CLOSE>=50`.

Right now, due to the `IIF` function constraint, I can only create a plot with 2 colors. Below is how I did it with 2 colors.

```
Plot( PCT_CLOSE , "CLOSE", IIf(PCT_CLOSE<=50, colorRed, colorYellow), styleNoTitle | styleLine | styleThick );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Color criteria in question:

> color is red when PCT_CLOSE<=25, yellow when between 25 and 50, Green
>   when PCT_CLOSE>=50

The key is to have nested IIF statements. Put IIF inside IIF.
Here is the corresponding code;

```
color = IIf(PCT_CLOSE<=25, colorRed, IIf(PCT_CLOSE>50, colorGreen, colorYellow)  )
```